# Query Syntax Error Missing Operator

Tags: sql

I got a problem with my Database. The assignment is to find the books (Book NR's) that are Dutch and Unavailable.

I'm using this code.

```
SELECT BOOKNR, RUBRIEK
FROM  BOOKS
WHERE RUBRIEK = 'Dutch'
AND
WHERE  BOOKNR IN
(
SELECT  BOOKNR
FROM   COPYS
WHERE  STATUS = "Unavailible"
)
```

I'm getting Syntax Error Missing Operator.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Only one `WHERE` keyword allowed per level of `SELECT`.  `WHERE RUBRIEK = 'Dutch' AND BOOKNR IN (SELECT BOOKNR FROM COPYS WHERE STATUS = 'Unavailable')` . Don't repeat `WHERE` outside the subquery

Comment: Thanks! But what should the code become now? Im just a beginner sorry for that.

Comment: @Jesse -- Exactly what Michael posted... -- just remove your second where.  Voting to close as I don't see how this could help anyone else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amended (fair point on the downvote):

```
WHERE  BOOKNR IN
```

should be

```
BOOKNR IN
```

You don't want the extra `WHERE`

Also

```
WHERE  STATUS = "Unavailible"
```

*might* need to be

```
WHERE  STATUS = 'Unavailible'
```

Comment: Didnt solve the issue. Any more solutions?

Comment: Some RDBMS support double quoted strings. But if this is Oracle as the cryptic error message implies, then it must be single-quoted

Comment: Apologies, there's also an extra `WHERE` you need to remove, which I stupidly missed when jumping in with my answer.

Comment: YES THIS SOLVED THE ISSUE. THANKS. (will accept as solved in 5 mins.)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT BOOKNR, RUBRIEK
FROM  BOOKS
WHERE RUBRIEK = 'Dutch'
AND
BOOKNR IN
(
SELECT  BOOKNR
FROM   COPYS
WHERE  STATUS = "Unavailible"
)
```